# How to install dpkg without dpkg, apt and ar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, dpkg

Today I've uninstalled bash on my wsl system (because I wanted to be very funny). But I think that bash had references to `apt` and `dpkg`. So after I ran the command `sudo apt remove bash` everything was gone.

It's not really a problem, because there is no important data or so. I just wanted to know how to reinstall everything again.

I've already googled and I've found out that `apt` needs `dpkg` so I need to install `dpkg` so that I can install the apt deb with `dpkg`. To install `dpkg` I've already downloaded the deb and extracted the `data.tar.gz`, but I've no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you uninstalled dpkg you can't install it again using a deb since you will need dpkg to install dpkg!
You might want to try this other [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/474681/70620) from the AskUbuntu forum.
Technically you can also build and install dpkg from the source code but I would recommend you reinstall your system since you have no important data on it.